# Floating Touch - How to detect if someone hover screen using Qt on Android

Tags: android, qt, qml, qt5

I'm looking to do *floating touch* -- hover the phone screen up to few millimeters without touching it.

Not sure how it is called. I don't know the name of the class/techno to use that's the reason why I posted the behavior which is to be able to hover the screen with your hands/fingers without touching it.

Can I accomplish that using Qt on Android?

For example: in a mobile phone, instead of taping "Settings" to access/open setting options, you just hover your finger over "Settings" then it act as you tapped it. That's what I want to accomplish.

Sony implemented Hover up to 22mm away (https://www.theverge.com/2012/3/14/2871193/sony-xperia-sola-floating-touch-hover-event-screen-technology)

Comment: So, you're asking a question that you don't have a clue about? Ok, just smiling ... As for the question - what is the difference between hovering and clicking in your opinion? Anyway, you could emulate whatever you want - for example - enter & move the area.

Comment: Folibis : It's wise to stay quiet if you know nothing instead wasting time writing nonsense stories. I really have a clue of what I'm asking, I even already found it for android... but i'm looking for the same thing to be done in Qt Android cause i'm a Qt developer, not Android one. If your skilled is limited, there are many people out there who can clearly answer my question.   Here is the Android version [link to Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027282/change-an-image-on-hover-without-touching-the-screen-in-android)

Comment: Ok, with this approach, I can only wish you good luck in getting an answer.

Comment: Take a look at [ProximitySensor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtsensors-proximitysensor.html), maybe that can help you

Comment: Thanks Folibis. But I still can't find how to **Hover** on the screen... as the link you provided me is full of class that's not related to Hover event. Also My apologies about my first reply. I also asked in Qt forum but they don't seem to give me the exact answer too.

Comment: Few tips, hope will be useful: Samsung has [SPen SDK](https://developer.samsung.com/dev/sPenMainList.do), regarding it there is question [Samsung hovering API with finger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308986/samsung-hovering-api-with-finger).

Comment: Thank you so much Troyane. That's what I wanted as I'm also testing using Samsung Phone